# Detect Canvas Image Overlapping Other Canvas Image Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Python 3.5.2

I'm trying to get an output from when a `canvas.create_image`overlaps another `canvas.create_image`. When I try to `canvas.find_overlapping` I get the error message: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)`

Here is the code:

```
finish = canvas.create_image(100, 200, image=img2, anchor='nw')
img = canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=img1, anchor='nw')
def checkfinish():
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.coords(img)
    result = canvas.find_overlapping(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    if finishline in result:
        print('overlaps')
    root.after(250, checkfinish)
```

Note: canvas, img1 ect. have already been defined, this is only relevant code.

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be assuming that `canvas.coords(img)` returns more than it actually does.

Comment: Is `canvas.coords()` only for shapes like `canvas.create_rectangle`?

Comment: not it's for all canvas objects. An image only has a single x/y coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you need the *bounding box* of the image, rather than the coordinates. Change the first line in `checkfinish` to this:

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = canvas.bbox(img)
```